# How to handle the volume of a source with obs-studio-node lib

Tags: javascript, node.js, obs, obs-studio

The initial volume is set to 1. After setting it to 0, I can't get it back to 1 despite all my trials. I also would like to modulate the volume with intermediate levels but it only goes to 0 when I try.

```
// example
console.log(item.source.volume) // 1
item.source.volume = 0
console.log(item.source.volume) // 0
item.source.volume = 1
console.log(item.source.volume) // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a fader:

```
const source = osn.InputFactory.create(...);
const fader = osn.FaderFactory.create(0); //Create a cubic fader
fader.attach(source);
fader.mul = 0.2; //Your volume from 0 - 1
```

spent hours trying to do this

This [WoW recorder](https://github.com/aza547/wow-recorder/) was a great resource for obs-studio-node. Shoutout to OBS and Streamlabs for having terrible documentation.